# history.replace in react-router-dom v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've previously used `react-router-dom v5.2.0`. There I used `history.replace('/path)` to redirect the page to another page. (Hence it will not store in the address history). Now I have to use `react-router-dom v6.0.0-beta.0`. In version 6, I have to use `useNavigate` hook instead of `useHistory` hook. I can use it as below.

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
navigate('/path')
```

But I don't know how to use it for redirect. (Like `history.replace`)

Comment: for v6.8: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/navigate

Answer (score 63, accepted):

If you need to replace the current location instead of push a new one onto the history stack, use `navigate(to, { replace: true })`. If you need state, use `navigate(to, { state })`.

Comment: For the sake of starters, it'd look like this `navigate("/login", { replace: true })`

Answer (score 7):

If you trying to replace the current path with another one, you should add **../** before the new path so basically:

```
navigate("../login", { replace: true })
```