# replace: true in React router v6 doesn't replace last entry in the history

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

The following code does not replace the last entry in the history stack:

```js
// inside some component
const navigate = useNavigate()

// inside a hook or click handler
navigate('/someroute', {replace: true})
// ..
```

I have checked [navigateFunction interface](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate#type-declaration) on documentation but can't tell what I'm doing wrong.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68694698/16407971 - This accepted answer does *not* replace the last item in the history stack in [a demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-spence-wchbop?file=/src/App.js) I have set up for demonstration (using CRA locally but sharing code in Codesandbox). It just keeps pushing new URLs instead of replacing the last one. (created simple `count` state to generate new URLs for `navigate`):

```js
<button
  onClick={() => {
    navigate(`/another${count}`, { replace: true })
    setCount((prevCount) => prevCount + 1)
  }}
>
```

Why isn't this sandbox code working? (Edit: I mistakingly edited Codesandbox instead of testing things locallly. It should be `{replace: true}` in the below code. Even so, the problem still persists.)

```
export default function App() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          navigate(`/another${count}`, { options: { replace: true } });
          setCount((prev) => prev + 1);
        }}
      >
        CLICK ME {count}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code in the sandbox is incorrect. The `navigate` function takes a second argument that ***is*** the options object. In other words, instead of

```
navigate(`/another${count}`, { options: { replace: true } });
```

it should be

```
navigate(`/another${count}`, { replace: true });
```

You've got it correct in the code snippet in your question though.

To be clear, the code in your sandbox is in fact PUSHing new entries onto the history state since the `replace` option isn't specified correctly instead of REPLACE.

```
export default function App() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          navigate(
            `/another${count}`,
            { options: { replace: true } } // <-- not a REPLACE, but a PUSH
          );
          setCount((prev) => prev + 1);
        }}
      >
        CLICK ME {count}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the full code that is working correctly:

```
export default function App() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          navigate(`/another${count}`, { replace: true }); // <-- REPLACE
          setCount((prev) => prev + 1);
        }}
      >
        CLICK ME {count}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit replace-true-in-react-router-v6-doesnt-replace-last-entry-in-the-history]

Comment: I have tried other approach (passing in object with `options` key) when the "correct snippet" didn't work. The solution that you provide is the one that doesn't work in my demo locally (exact code that I have in Codesandbox, just using `{replace: true}` instead of options object), nor in my side project that uses React router v6.

Comment: @semi_92 The code seems to be working as I'd expect it to. I added a working fork of your sandbox to my answer, but here it is as well: https://codesandbox.io/s/replace-true-in-react-router-v6-doesnt-replace-last-entry-in-the-history-6buezi. Using ```navigate(`/another${count}`, { replace: true });``` replaces the current history stack entry and there is no back navigation available.

Comment: Looks like I've misunderstood this function. What I was looking for is a way to replace last entries in the browser as they pile up: https://imgur.com/a/vhuw09h (using a simple useEffect that changes document title according to count). So the link with the title "7" would replace all the links below it (1 through 6). Is there something available for this use case?

Comment: @semi_92 Well, if you are using REPLACE "redirects" on the client side then these entries don't build up in the first place. Can you clarify the use case you are going for?

Comment: Well, they do pile up in my demo, using `{replace: true}` as a second arg (however, the back navigation is not available, as it shouldn't be). That's why I thought I misunderstood the function. I have a `navigate` call in a `useEffect` hook that changes URL every few seconds and renders a new page (slideshow website). History entries pile up, as they do with my demo.

Comment: @semi_92 That's very odd behavior that I just simply can't reproduce using `{ replace: true }`. Try it in the sandbox's [fullscreen view](https://6buezi.csb.app/another7). The URL updates... but there aren't any history entries building up to go back to. I've no idea what you are doing that is still creating history entries other than a normal PUSH somewhere. Do you have another sandbox using `{ replace: true }` that reproduces the history stack still building up that we could inspect?

Comment: I tried that Codesandbox in fullscreen view and the history still builds up. Again, this is what I mean by "building/piling up" https://imgur.com/a/d0AE6z0. However, the back button is disabled, so it looks like it works on the website but behind the scenes still pushes to history.

Comment: @semi_92 What, or where, exactly is building up? What browser are you using? Are you keeping a manual history list somewhere and rendering a list based on it?

Comment: I'm using Brave browser. When I click on the button in demo, new entries are being added in the browser history (accessed with ctrl + H), even when using `{replace: true}`. I'm not rendering anything with it, just want to stop this behavior since lots of images can be cycled through in the slideshow and pollute the history. I want to replace last browser history entry with the last item in the slideshow (the last link app navigates to). So, the browser history should list "7" instead of 1 through 7 from this example: https://imgur.com/a/A5AOp0R

Comment: @semi_92 That seems to be an issue with the Browser then, not the React app.

Comment: Tried with Firefox and Chrome as well, same behavior. https://imgur.com/a/wW6qquk

Comment: I don't exactly know what you are looking at, but if you long click/press the back button do you see history entries collecting there? I think you are looking a history of pages you've visited, and not the *actual* history stack.

Comment: You're correct. I'm looking at history of pages visited, not the actual stack (didn't know they were different). And that's why I said I might have misunderstood the function. Is there a way to modify visited pages that is demonstrated in my screencast? I thought `{replace: true}` would also work on the history of pages I've visited.

Comment: @semi_92 No, not that I'm aware of, they were visited pages afterall.