# Is there a way to change URL without redirecting with react router 6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I want to change the pathname from /account/ to /account/dashboard, /account/settings, and so on, and according to the pathname, render a different component. Is there a way to change the pathname without redirecting?

The only way I found so far is adding all the routes to App.tsx but that would mean also passing all the data these components take as props from App.tsx which I don't want to do.

Comment: What should happen when someone just types `/account/dashboard` into the address bar?

Comment: Is this what you need? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68694012/history-replace-in-react-router-dom-v6

Comment: @KonradLinkowski in this particular case it doesn't matter, I don't need the user to be redirected, but I think I know where you're getting at and it would be useful to know how to do it if the user should be redirected

Comment: @Eloi no, navigate redirects you to the url rather than just changing the pathname

Comment: The address bar is something that the user can edit at any time. If something is dependent on the url it means the user can just go anywhere and the app should always work in that case. You are trying to create a bug or bad UX

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I mean, I only need to render different components in a dashboard based on the pathname. I am not sure how that would create any bug or bad UX

Comment: You can use `useRoutes` and define routes in the `account` component, but it will be a redirection in fact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `useRoutes`

```
const router = useRoutes([
  { element: <Dashboard />, path: "dashboard" },
  // you can pass props
  { element: <Settings color={color} />, path: "settings" }
]);
```

Example:

```
const Account = () => {
  const router = useRoutes([
    { element: <Dashboard />, path: "dashboard" },
    { element: <Settings />, path: "settings" }
  ]);

  return (
    <div>
      {router}
    </div>
  )
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-river-71sh5x?file=/src/App.js